# Find smaller subset when comparing elements in two lists of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

Sorry if this is complicated, but I'll try to explain this as best I can. I have two lists of lists with the same number of elements but organized in a different way, for example:

```
a = [1],[2,3,4],[5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12,13]
b = [1,2,3,4],[5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12],[13]
```

I'm trying to 1) find what are the differing lists between the two lists of lists, and 2) for each differing list, find the length of the smaller subset. Hence, for list a, [1] and [2,3,4] are subsets of [1,2,3,4] in b - therefore, [1] is the smaller subset and its length is 1.

I'm able to create a list of differing lists for both a and b via:

```
matches = [x for x in a if x in b]
adiff = [x for x in a if x not in matches]
bdiff = [x for x in b if x not in matches]
```

However, I can't seem to get to part 2. Is this possible in python?

Edit: Sorry, the list in b should be [5,6]. So the desired output when a is compared against b is 1, given that the length of [1] is 1. When b is compared against a, the desired output is also 1 since the length of [13] is also 1.

Comment: Both the lists always will have equal number of elements and you want to compare element by element from both the lists?

Comment: For me, `for each differing list, find the length of the smaller subset` means the minimum length of each list, `a` and `b`, so here, `1` for `a` ([1]), and `1` for `b` ([13]). Could you provide an exact output of what you're looking for ?

Comment: Can you add desired O/p ?

Comment: Is the list `b` wrong? It contains `[6,5]`, yet `a` contains `[5,6]`

Comment: Yea, I'd like to compare element by element

Comment: Can you assert that lists are always strict subsets  in one direction only? i.e., things like `a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]; b = [[1], [2, 3], [4]]` are impossible?

Comment: Nitpicking: `a` and `b`from the given code are tuples not lists.

Comment: What if `a = [1,2],[3,4]` and `b = [3,4],[1,2]`?

Comment: @Arne Recknagel The lists are always strict subsets, but can be in both directions. So `a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]; b = [[1], [2, 3], [4]]` is impossible, but `a = [[1], [2], [3, 4]]; b = [[1, 2], [3], [4]]` is possible.

Comment: @tobias_k Then these would be considered matches and filtered out by the `matches = [x for x in a if x in b]` part.

Comment: How do you want to represent the result? Do you just want a list of indices of `shortest_subsets` for either list?

Comment: are the lists ordered?

Comment: @Arne Recknagel That could work as well! I can just calculate the lengths from that list.

Comment: @Maarten Fabré The lists within the lists are ordered, but the list of lists are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are treating those lists of lists rather as sets, with order seemingly not being important and regarding subsets and the like, it might help to actually convert those to sets of sets (or actually, `set` of `frozenset`). Then, you can use `set` operations like `&`, `^`, `<` or `-` to find the result.

```
>>> a = [1],[2,3,4],[5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12,13]
>>> b = [1,2,3,4],[5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12],[13]
>>> aset = set(map(frozenset, a))
>>> bset = set(map(frozenset, b))
>>> aset & bset
{frozenset({5, 6}), frozenset({7, 8, 9})}
>>> [min(sub, key=len) for sub in ([y for y in aset if y < x] for x in bset - aset) if sub]
[frozenset({1})]
>>> [min(sub, key=len) for sub in ([y for y in bset if y < x] for x in aset - bset) if sub]
[frozenset({13})]
```

Or for finding pairs of superset and smallest subset:

```
>>> [(x, min((y for y in bset if y < x), key=len, default=None)) for x in aset - bset]
[(frozenset({10, 11, 12, 13}), frozenset({13})),
 (frozenset({2, 3, 4}), None),
 (frozenset({1}), None)]
```

Comment: Does that still work if the list elements have text instead of just numbers? For instance, does the element [buses] get converted to set(b, e, s, u)?

Comment: @darrrn Yes, it should work for lists of lists of strings. The plain string `"buses"` would be converted to `{'b', 'u', 's', 'e'}`, but the list `["buses"]` becomes the set `{"buses"}`.

Comment: k Thank you! That did it =)

Comment: does this still work if `a=[1,2,3]` and `b=[1],[2],[3]`?

Comment: @darrrn I don't see why it should not, but of course it depends on what output you expect in this case. I'm getting `{2}`.